# Tween object array elements to one corner on touch-LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tween, universal-tween-engine

In my game,I have array of coins appearing on a particular action.Once I touch the coins,coins have to move off smoothly(like flying) to one corner of the screen,one by one.
I am creating and drawing coin array like this:

```
private Coin coins[] = new Coin[10];//coin array

for(int i=0;i<coins.length;i++) {
    coins[i]=objectFactory.createCoin();//creating object array of coins
}
```

draw coins

```
 for(int i=0;i<coins.length;i++) {
    coinTexture = coinAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
    batch.draw(coinTexture,coins[i].getX(), coins[i].getY());
}
```

for detecting touch on coin:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
         game.camera.unproject(touchPos);
         for(int i=0;i<coins.length;i++){
             Rectangle textureBounds=new Rectangle(coins[i].getX(),coins[i].getY(),coins[i].getWidth(),coins[i].getHeight());    
             if(textureBounds.contains(touchPos.x,touchPos.y)) {
                 System.out.println("u touched the coin!!!!!!!!");
             }
        }
}
```

I now want to use Universal TweenEngine to tween it on touch to the corner of the screen.I am completely new to the concept of tween engine.
I am not able to find any helpful documentation on how to achieve this affect with tween engine.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tween engine in your project, inject these dependency in core module

```
compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4'
compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4:sources'
```

These artifacts are available in `https://jitpack.io` so add this repo in project.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Create `CoinAccessor`

```
public class CoinAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Coin> {

    public static final int POS_XY = 1;
    public static final int CPOS_XY = 2;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Coin target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
            case POS_XY:
                returnValues[0] = target.getX();
                returnValues[1] = target.getY();
                return 2;

            case CPOS_XY:
                returnValues[0] = target.getX() + target.getWidth()/2;
                returnValues[1] = target.getY() + target.getHeight()/2;
                return 2;

            default: assert false; return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Coin target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
            case POS_XY: target.setPosition(newValues[0], newValues[1]); 
            break;

            case CPOS_XY: target.setPosition(newValues[0] - target.getWidth()/2, newValues[1] - target.getHeight()/2); 
            break;

            default: assert false;
        }
    }
}
```

Register `CoinAccessor` with `Coin` and update `TweenManager`.

When there is a proper touch on Coin

```
Tween.to(coin[i], CoinAccessor.POS_XY, 0.8f).target(targetX,targetY).start(tweenManager);
```

**EDIT**

For registration there is static method `registerAccessor` for the same.

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Coin.class, new CoinAccessor());
```

Call `update()` method of `TweenManager` in your game's update/render method to update tween manager.

```
TweenManager tweenManager = new TweenManager();
tweenManager.update(dt);   // this call should be in render/update method
```

Comment: will you please explain how this POS_XY and CPOS_XY  works with switch  case here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post code for registering with accessor and updating TweenManager.

Comment: Worked perfectly!Thank you!